# Is it possible to check a numpy dtype without caring for the size?

Tags: python, numpy, types

I want to have an object of numpy dtype, and simply check whether it is of int type or not, without caring if it has nbytes=32, 64, ...

Is there a way of quickly and simply doing this?

For example:

```
val = np.array([[2], [3], [4]]).astype(np.int32)
print val.type
>>> int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.issubdtype()` function:

```
In [44]: np.issubdtype(val.dtype, np.int)
Out[44]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

[`val.dtype.kind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) will give you `i` for any integer type.